# How to code a Where Clause to deliver data based on a parameter selection

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SSRS and SSMS 2008 R2. I have 2 reports that the user wants combined into 1 report with the option to select
a date to get data for 2013 or 2014. All the datasets in both reports are identical except for one
dataset in each report that has different hardcoded Where Clause values for the 2013 group verses the 2014 group of clients. 
I thought I could do a CASE statement in the Where clause to select the hardcoded 2013 group or the 2014 group based on the @Startdate parameter,
but that did not work, any ideas on how to do this?

Here is the 2013 query and 2014 Query that the Where Clause is the only difference between the 2 reports:

```
    SELECT [FISCAL YEAR]
,COUNT(*) AS EXPECTED
,SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON T1.primarykey = T2.primarykey
WHERE Field1 IN (
        5555
        ,6666
        )
    AND Field2 IN (
        2222
        ,3333
        )
    AND YEAR(T1.DATE) = YEAR(@StartDate)
    AND T1.AMOUNT >= 25000
    AND T1.DESCRIPTION IN (
        'The Campaign - YYY - 2011-2015'
    ,'The Campaign - ZZZ - 2011-2015'
    ,'2013 AAA Goal'
    ,'2013 BBB Goal'
    ,'2013 CCC Goal'
    ,'2013 DDD Goal'
    ,'2013 EEE'
    ,'2013 FFF'
    )
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.DATE, 1), 2)

SELECT [FISCAL YEAR]
    ,COUNT(*) AS EXPECTED
    ,SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON T1.primarykey = T2.primarykey
WHERE Field1 IN (
        5555
        ,6666
        )
    AND Field2 IN (
        2222
        ,3333
        )
    AND YEAR(T1.DATE) = YEAR(@StartDate)
    AND T1.AMOUNT >= 25000
    AND T1.DESCRIPTION IN (
        'The Campaign - YYY - 2011-2015'
        ,'The Campaign - ZZZ - 2011-2015'
        ,'2014 AAA Goal'
        ,'2014 BBB Goal'
        ,'2014 CCC Goal'
        ,'2014 DDD Goal'
        ,'2014 EEE'
        ,'2014 FFF'
        ,'2014 GGG'
        ,'2014 HHH'
        ,'2014 JJJ'
        ,'2014 LLL'
        )
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.DATE, 1), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing you table and database.  I would union all between two query and add parameter on the union with a new year column.

```
Select * from 
(
SELECT [FISCAL YEAR]
,COUNT(*) AS EXPECTED
,SUM(Amount) AS Total, YEAR(T1.DATE) as 'pYear'
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON T1.primarykey = T2.primarykey
WHERE Field1 IN (
        5555
        ,6666
        )
    AND Field2 IN (
        2222
        ,3333
        )
    --AND YEAR(T1.DATE) = YEAR(@StartDate)
    AND T1.AMOUNT >= 25000
    AND T1.DESCRIPTION IN (
        'The Campaign - YYY - 2011-2015'
    ,'The Campaign - ZZZ - 2011-2015'
    ,'2013 AAA Goal'
    ,'2013 BBB Goal'
    ,'2013 CCC Goal'
    ,'2013 DDD Goal'
    ,'2013 EEE'
    ,'2013 FFF'
    )
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.DATE, 1), 2)
Union ALL
SELECT [FISCAL YEAR]
    ,COUNT(*) AS EXPECTED
    ,SUM(Amount) AS Total, YEAR(T1.DATE) as 'pYear'
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 T2
    ON T1.primarykey = T2.primarykey
WHERE Field1 IN (
        5555
        ,6666
        )
    AND Field2 IN (
        2222
        ,3333
        )
    --AND YEAR(T1.DATE) = YEAR(@StartDate)
    AND T1.AMOUNT >= 25000
    AND T1.DESCRIPTION IN (
        'The Campaign - YYY - 2011-2015'
        ,'The Campaign - ZZZ - 2011-2015'
        ,'2014 AAA Goal'
        ,'2014 BBB Goal'
        ,'2014 CCC Goal'
        ,'2014 DDD Goal'
        ,'2014 EEE'
        ,'2014 FFF'
        ,'2014 GGG'
        ,'2014 HHH'
        ,'2014 JJJ'
        ,'2014 LLL'
        )
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, T1.DATE, 1), 2)
) as t 
where pYear =YEAR(@StartDate)
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you for your help! Was getting an error of P.DATE_EXPECTED is invalid in select list because it is not contained in the Group BY list. (I am using 'FY' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, P.DATE_EXPECTED, 1), 2)+ ' - YTD' AS [FISCAL YEAR] for T1.Date). So I added P.DATE_EXPECTED to the Group By. Then I got 16 rows back with duplicate data for 2 sets of 8 rows with different totals and counts for each 8. I need one row to come back that totals the count and it sums the amount for each fiscal year. Like Fiscal year = FY14 Expected = 24 Total = $24,000,000 pYear = 2014

Comment: Please modified my answer so it help other. Thx